# how to stop getting input from user when press enter?

Tags: perl

I am getting Input data from user by using

```
$input=<>;
```

But when type <kbd>Enter</kbd> it won't go next process it accept <kbd>Enter</kbd> character also but only go when type `^z` but i want go next process when press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

The code you have presented in itself does not do what you say it does. It simply reads one line and then moves on. In scalar context, the [`readline()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) function (for which  using angle brackets `<>` is a shortcut) is an iterator, and reads one line at the time until the file handle is exhausted (it reaches end of file).

There are two things that may account for this behaviour:

1. You have changed the input record separator `$/` so that it no longer takes newline to denote end of line,
2. You are really using a list context, an array or parentheses, e.g.:

---

```
@input = <>;
# or
($input) = <>;
```

In the first case, it will read until it finds the input record separator and return that (multiline) string to be assigned to the `$input` variable. You can terminate it prematurely by pressing sending end of file: Ctrl-Z in windows, or Ctrl-D in *nix.

In the second case, the `readline()` is in list context, and will read until it finds end of file, which is the thing discussed above.

Comment: A third possibility is that it's really `while ($input = <>)`, although you'd think that one would be pretty obvious.

Comment: @cjm And yet, I suspect that is exactly what's going on.

Comment: I want terminate getting input from user by using enter button instead of ^z

Comment: In my program i am using undef $/; so it possible to exit when press enter while using undef $/;

Comment: No, it is not possible, because setting `$/` to undef disables enter (newline) as end of line character.